# How to stop Jquery executing on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of Jquery which I am using to force a div to have a 'slide in' effect upon a user clicking on another div (a button which I define). However, upon page load, the jquery has executed and the div which is supposed to slide in upon user click, has already appeared and been revealed. Please can someone tell me how to stop this, and make it so that it's not active upon page load, and only works upon user click. Thanks.

Here is my code :

```
$( "#open-nav-3" ).click(function() {
  $( "#open-nav-menus" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

open-nav-3 is the button which the user clicks to make the content appear, and open-nav-menus is the div ( content ) which appears.

I expect this is probably very simple, but I am a novice with all things Javascript.

Comment: "with all things Java" Doh, once again. http://kb.mozillazine.org/JavaScript_is_not_Java

Comment: take it out of `$(function(){...});`

Comment: I do know the difference, I just wrote it in a hurry and didn't think.

Comment: Well, you should think before hitting the "Post Your Question" button – at least you are asking other people to think for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you just need an additional

```
$( "#open-nav-menus" ).hide();
```

to hide the element on page load. Add it before the event handler:

```
var navMenu = $( "#open-nav-menus" );
navMenu.hide();
$( "#open-nav-3" ).click(function() {
    navMenu.slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

Comment: Thank-you very much indeed :) Worked a treat. P.s. on the 'java' thing ... it was a minor mistake .... everyone makes them